# Where can I find open-source CSS animations

Tags: css, animation

Anyone know where I can find open-source CSS animations that I can apply to my site.

I've played with CSS3 a lot, but not much with animations, and I'd like to see what the open-source community offers before I try to build one on my own. Because truth be told, I find it scary.

Comment: http://html5center.sourceforge.net/Build-Awesome-Apps-with-CSS3-Animations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like these one they are quite nice:

http://daneden.me/animate/

My advice is take it one key-frame at a time. It is just styling at different parts of the animation represented by the percent of progress (keyframes).